# Why does this mysql query return an integer as a string?

Tags: mysql, string, if-statement, integer

I am currently practicing MySQL on LeetCode. I have recieved the following information:

ID is the primary key column for this table. Each row of this table contains information about the salary of an employee. Write an SQL query to report the second highest salary from the Employee table. If there is no second highest salary, the query should report null.

I have created the following query:

```
SELECT IF((SELECT count(*) FROM employee) = 1, 'null', salary) as SecondHighestSalary
FROM Employee
LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1
```

It gives the requested answer, except that the output is given as a string. For example if the salary column consists of the values 100, 200 and 300. My query outputs "200" and not 200. When I remove the IF-statement and just pull the second salary, it returns the integer 200.

Why does MySQL return an integer as a string when I use the IF statement?

Comment: Remove the quotes around null

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

You used `'null'` in your `IF` which is a string and according to the [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/flow-control-functions.html#function_if) the type of the output will be a string.
You should use `NULL` in your `IF` instead:

```
SELECT IF((SELECT count(*) FROM employee) = 1, NULL, salary) ....
```